# OAuth 2: Problems to get access token

Tags: spring, curl, oauth, spring-boot

I just started to work with OAuth and Spring Boot and did a basic application to see it in action.

Here is my MySQL schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `role` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`role`)
)

CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `activationkey` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `resetpasswordkey` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
)

CREATE TABLE `user_role` (
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `USER_FK` (`username`),
  KEY `ROLE_FK` (`role`),
  CONSTRAINT `ROLE_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`role`) REFERENCES `role` (`role`),
  CONSTRAINT `USER_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES `user` (`name`)
)
```

And the data:

```sql
INSERT INTO `role` VALUES ('1', 'ROLE_ADMIN');
INSERT INTO `role` VALUES ('3', 'ROLE_GUEST');
INSERT INTO `role` VALUES ('2', 'ROLE_USER');

INSERT INTO `user` VALUES ('Leonardo', 'leonardo', 'leonardo.mora@datys.cu', 'admin', '1', null, null);

INSERT INTO `user_role` VALUES ('leonardo', 'ROLE_ADMIN', '0');
```

And the code:

```java
/**
* My CustomUserDetailService
*/
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CustomUserDetailService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("User %s does not exist!", username));
        }
        return new UserRepositoryUserDetails(user);
    }

    private static class UserRepositoryUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails {

        private UserRepositoryUserDetails(User user) {
            super(user);
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            return getRoles();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return getEnabled();
        }
    }
}
```

OAuth Configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class Oauth2JdbcSample extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "cenergy";

    /**
     * Esta clase es para configurar el servidor de recursos
     *
     * @author leonardo.mora
     */
    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources)
                throws Exception {
            resources
                    .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()                    
                    .antMatchers("/users")
                    .authenticated();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Esta clase es para configurar el servidor de autorizacion
     *
     * @author leonardo.mora
     */
    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

        @Autowired        
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private CustomUserDetailService userDetailsService;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            endpoints.tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
                    .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
                    .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off          
            clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient("cenergy-client")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
                    .authorities("ROLE_ADMIN")
                    .scopes("read", "write")
                    .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                    .secret("123456")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(300);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
            DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
            tokenServices.setTokenStore(this.tokenStore);
            return tokenServices;
        }
    }
}
```

Web Security Configuration:

```java
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setSessionAttributeName("_csrf");
        return repository;
    }
}
```

Here is my access token request:

```sh
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
cenergy-client:123456@localhost:9191/api/oauth/token \
-d grant_type=password -d username=leonardo -d password=admin
```

which gives me the error:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing grant type"}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests to the token endpoint need to format their body as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` rather than `application/json`:

```bash
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  \
  cenergy-client:123456@localhost:9191/api/oauth/token        \
  -d grant_type=password -d username=leonardo -d password=admin
```

This is defined in the OAuth2 spec (for the password grant specifically in [Section 4.3.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2)):

> 4.3.2.  Access Token Request
>
> The client makes a request to the token endpoint [...] using the
> **"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"** format per [Appendix B](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#appendix-B) with a
> character encoding of UTF-8 in the HTTP request entity-body:

Comment: Thanks sthzg, i did try your solution, change my curl with curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" localhost:9191/api/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d username=leonardo -d password=admin -d client_id=cenergy-client and the result was {"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

Comment: @LeonardoMoraLópez it should work if you put the `client_id:password` before the host address in your Curl command (see the example in the answer), e.g. `cenergy-client:123456@localhost:9191/api/oauth/token`. also drop the `-d client_id=...` from Curl, since that parameter is not supported on the  token endpoint.

Comment: this is my curl: curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" cenergy-client:123456@localhost:9191/api/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d username=leonardo -d password=admin
now i get bad credential, look the result:
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Bad credentials"}* Closing connection 0